# Php Slim not handle errors with the custom errorHandler

Tags: php, slim

My custom error handler is not working with Slim 3 framework. Instead of getting a 500 error, I get a response with status 200 and the html error details are in the body.

Here is my minimal, verifiable and complete example:

```
$c = new \Slim\Container();
$c['errorHandler'] = function ($c) {
    return function($request, $response, $exception) use ($c) {
        return $c['response']->withStatus(500)
            ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            ->write('Something went wrong!');
    };
};

$app = new \Slim\App($c);

$app->any('/foo', function($request, $response, $args) {
    $data = json_encode($request->nonExistingMethod()); // error!
    return $response->withJson($data);
});

$app->run();
```

How do I need to refactor this sample to make it work? I suspect it's related with the Fatal nature of the error. But in this case how to deal with that?

Reference: http://www.slimframework.com/docs/handlers/error.html

**Edit 1**

For use in an api style web application, the final solution I'm using with minor changes from the response of this question:

```
function checkForError() {
  $last = error_get_last();

  if ($last) {
    @header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
    echo json_encode($last); // optional, includes error details in json format
  }
}

error_reporting(0);
register_shutdown_function('checkForError');
```

Comment: You're trying to JSON encode a non-existing method. What are your expectations? If you try to encode something that doesn't exist it's going to break.

Comment: It's a sample code to force an error. The problem is that the errorHandler is not working and I get a 200 response with html in body instead the 500 response from the errorHandler.

Comment: Okay, now I understand what you are saying. Do you need to register that error handler? http://docs.slimframework.com/errors/500/

Comment: This is the way in Slim 2, but I'm using Slim 3 and the register is different. I will update the question with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot catch all errors like this

there is however one way to catch all except memory errors (or only those that tried to allocate more than your error handler needs)

```
function checkForError() {
  $last = error_get_last();

  if ($last) {
    @header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
    echo 'we failed... sry';
  }
}

register_shutdown_function('checkForError');
```

updated with 500 status header

Comment: Is possible to adapt this code and return an 500 status code instead a 200 html or text message?

Comment: yes - just added the code - it is importat to use the @ in front of header since there could be some output that was sent to the client already

Comment: in addition the ob_clean() remove the html details of the error so I got a 'api like' response! thanks